# Setting the value of an enum member of an object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, arraylist, enums

There are three parts to this. First I have an enum

```
public enum myType {TYPEA, TYPEB}
```

Then I have a class with myType as a member

```
public class myClass{
    myType t;
    int example;
}
```

Finally I have an ArrayList of that class

```
ArrayList<myClass> theArray = new ArrayList<myClass>();
```

I fill the list and then I want to go back and change the value of t of a certain element in theArray, theoretically with something like the following:

```
theArray.get(i).t = TYPEA;
```

but this gives me a compiler error: symbol cannot be found.

I've tried searching around for accessing members of objects in ArrayLists and of editing enum values, all to no avail. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: try `theArray.get(i).t = myType.TYPEA;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it like this:

```
theArray.get(i).t = myType.TYPEA;
```